# How to compiled/encrypt the .js file?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to is there any way to compiled/encrypt the file? As the user cannot view the code. Thanks for in advanced.

Comment: You can *obfuscate* or *uglify* the client code, but it must be unencrypted for the browser to actually run it. Treat all client-side code as publicly available.

Comment: Is there anyway that to hide the code?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can only be obfuscated but, for most cases, that will be sufficient. You could use Google Closure Compiler which is a good choice for that.

https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home